# Testing strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, strong-parameters

I want to test my strong parameters in rails controllers. The best way I have found so far is the one described here: http://pivotallabs.com/rails-4-testing-strong-parameters/

Unfortunately this leads to "blacklist" testing: I can only test wether certain parameters are discarded. What I would like to do is "whitelist" testing: making sure that *only* certain parameters are permitted.

My idea was to figure out all attributes of the model, set them all to some value, and pass them to the class. Then I could test if only whitelisted parameters come through.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to set all attributes without knowing them. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually in `with` block in that article there will be only whitelisted elements. I mean:

```
User.should_receive(:create).
    with({name: 'Sideshow Bob'}.with_indifferent_access)
```

Hash `{name: 'Sideshow Bob'}` contains only white listed. So it exactly checks that *only* certain parameters are permitted.

BTW why someone need to test blacklist params, if they can be anything? All others is blacklisted.

Answer (score 1):

```
values = Model.new.attributes
values.each_key { |key| values[key] = 'abcdef' }
post :create, user: values
```

This will attempt to post with all of the potential attributes of a given model, from there you can verify that only the expected behavior happens.